# Rotativa form inline Bootstrap 4

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, rotativa

I have a problem with Rotativa and Bootstrap. I want to generate a PDF with an inline form but it doesn't display inline. I've made a basic example. I am returning a `PartialViewAsPdf` and the html is a simple inline form example with bootstrap 4(w3schools). Any ideas?

```
.cshtml
       <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
      <label for="email">Email address:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
      <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Controller

```
var actionPdf = new Rotativa.PartialViewAsPdf("File.cshtml", model);
return actionPdf
```

Expected result:
[image]

Actual Result

[image]

Comment: No idea without output and desired output. How are you generating the view? How are you generating the PDF?

Comment: @mxmissile it's ok now?

Answer (score 0):

Rotativa doesn't know about display:flex.Replace this with display:-webkit-box.